# Quelle eines Märchens mit einer Meeresschlange

Tags: literature

In einer historischen Butoh-Tanz Aufnahme ([1976, Geisen jo no okugata, Asbestos Hall](https://ugc.futurelearn.com/uploads/files/f1/e4/f1e4c9aa-6617-49b8-ba0d-4f47dab480be/Butoh_Week2_20190107s.pdf)) wird folgender Text rezitiert:

> Alle diejenigen, die als Kaufleute oder Fischer auf dem Norden diese Meeres gefahren sind, bezeugen einhellig ein wunderliches Ding.
> Das naemlich eine Schlange von unsaeglicher Groesse in den Bergen und Hoehlen an den Ufern des Bergener(?) Meeres hauset.
> Sie sei an die zweihundert und mehr Schuh lang und an die zwanzig Schuh dick.
> Nachts, wenn der Mond scheint, gehe sie aus ihren Loechern und fresse die Kaelber, Laemmer und Schweine auf dem Feld
> oder sie lasse sich ins Meer gleiten und fresse dort .. .. und andere Meerkrebse.
> Am Hals hat sie eine ellenlange Haar ... schwarze ...
> Dazu hat sie feuerrote glitzernde Augen. Wenn sie ihren Schiffen nachjagt, dann reckt sie sich in die Hoehe wie eine Saeule. So greift sie in die Schiffe, reist die Leute raus und frisst sie.
> Im Jahr 1522 ist sie gesehen worden, wie sie sich hoch ueber das Wasser empor ... und sich nachher in einen Ring zusammen ...
> Soviel man von der Ferne hatte beobachten koennen, hat man sie fuer 50 Ellen lang gehalten.

Der Text ist nicht an allen Stellen deutlich zu hören, daher die fehlenden Worte. Ich bin auf der Suche nach der Quelle für diesen Text, oder nach einer Inspiration für die Thematik im deutschsprachigen Märchenschatz.

Comment: Evtl hast du einen Link zur Quelle. Butoh ist ja japanischen Ursprungs, da kann es sich leicht um ein ursprünglich japanisches Märchen handeln, das nur übersetzt wurde. Seeschlangen sind nicht unbedingt ein klassisches europäisches Märchenmotiv ^^.

Comment: @mtwde Ich habe die Video/Audio Aufnahme von einem Butoh-Forscher zum Transkribieren bekommen, aber nicht oeffentlich. Die Auffuehrung wird allerdings an mehreren Stellen erwaehnt, siehe editierte Frage.

Comment: Spontan fällt mir die [Midgardschlange](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midgardschlange) aus der nordischen Mythologie ein, das würde auch zur Ortsangabe Bergen passen (wenn wir jetzt mal von Bergen in Norwegen ausgehen). Aber ob es Geschichten gibt, die die Grundlage für diesen Text bilden, ist mir nicht bekannt. Eventuell kann Dir auch jemand bei [Mythology & Folklore.SE](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) weiterhelfen.

Comment: Heißt das, dass in der Aufnahme ein deutscher Text vorgetragen wird?

Comment: @PaulFrost Ja, aber schwer zu verstehen weil die Sprecherin nicht Hochdeutsch spricht (oder eventuell anderssprachig ist) und weil es mit Musik unterlegt ist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es scheint auf einem Text von [Olaus Magnus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olaus_Magnus) zu beruhen, in dem die **norwegische Seeschlange** beschrieben wird. Auf diese Spur kam ich über [Johannes Prätorius](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Praetorius_(Schriftsteller)). Zitat aus Wikipedia:

> Zwar hielt er [Johannes Prätorius] gelegentlich Vorlesungen, doch verbrachte er den wesentlichsten Teil seiner Zeit in emsiger schriftstellerischer Tätigkeit, vornehmlich als Kompilator von Märchen und kuriosen Legenden. Insgesamt veröffentlichte er mehr als 50 Bücher. Für die Nachwelt wurde er unvergesslich vor allem durch seine Sammlung der Rübezahl-Sagen.

[Einige Formulierungen](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Praetorius,+Johannes/Prosa/Anthropodemus+plutonicus/Ander+Theil+der+Newen+Weltbeschreibung/18.+Von+See-Menschen) des Textes findet man in

> Johannes Prätorius, Anthropodemus plutonicus, Ander Theil der Newen Weltbeschreibung, Kapitel 18 "Von See-Menschen"

Zitat:

> Es sey auch / schreibet er ferner im 43. Capitel ein sehr grosse Schlange in der Insul Moos / nach Hammeren gehörig / welche / wie der Comet der Welt / also diese dem Königreiche Nordwegen eine Veränderung verkündige / in massen sie im Jahr 1522. hoch über dem Wasser sich erhebende / gesehen worden; Darauff die Verjagung König Christianus deß Andern / und die schwere Verfolgung der Praelaten erfolget sey.

Von Prätorius werden diese Informationen Olaus Magnus zugeschrieben. Sie scheinen zu stammen aus

> Olaus Magnus, Historia de gentibus septentrionalibus (Rom 1555).

Siehe [hier](https://mythicalcreatures.edwardworthlibrary.ie/dragons/sea-serpent-of-norway/).

Zitat:

> They who in Works of Navigation, on the Coasts of Norway, employ themselves in fishing or Merchandise, to all agree in this strange story, that there is a Serpent there which is of a vast magnitude, namely 200 foot long, and more over 20 foot thick; and is wont to live in Rocks and Caves toward the Sea-cost about Berge: which will go alone from his holes in a clear night, in Summer, and devour Calves, Lambs, and Hogs, or else he goes into the Sea to feed on Polypus, Locusts, and all sorts of Sea-Crabs. He had commonly hair hanging from his neck a Cubit long, and sharp Scales, and is black, and he hath flaming shining eys. This Snake disquiets the Shippers, and he puts up his head on high like a pillar, and catcheth away men, and he devours them; {and this hapneth not, but it signifies some wonderful changes of the Kingdom near at hand; namely that the Princes shall die, or be banished; or some Tumultous Wars shall presently follow. There is also another Serpent of an incredible magnitude in a Town, called Moos, or the Diocese of Hammer; which, as a Comet portends a change in all the World, so, that portends a change in the Kingdom of Norway, as} it was seen, Anno 1522, that lifts himself high above the Waters, and rouls himself round like a sphere. This Serpent was thought to be fifty Cubits long by conjecture, by sight afar off: {there followed this the banishment of King Christiernus, and a great persecution of the Bishops; and it shew’d also the destruction of the Countrey.}

Sicher gibt es davon auch eine deutsche Übersetzung. Ich vermute jedenfalls, dass der deutsche Text in der Frage nicht eigens für die Aufnahme geschrieben wurde, sondern dass es sich um ein wörtliches Zitat aus einer noch unbekannten Quelle handelt. Olaus Magnus mischt geschichtliche Fakten mit phantastischen Elementen, die unbekannte Quelle greift nur letztere auf (wohl zur Erbauung der Leser) und lässt die von mir in Klammern { ... } gesetzten Sätze des Originaltextes weg.

Einige andere nützliche Referenzen sind
[1](https://brewminate.com/olaus-magnus-sea-serpent/),
[2](http://www.islamicmanuscripts.info/reference/books/Fansa-2009-Wege/Fansa-2009-Wege-1-194-200-Bietz.pdf), [3](https://www.welt.de/geschichte/article145826295/Die-Wahrheit-hinter-den-Seeungeheuern-der-Weltmeere.html), [4](https://www.suso.schulen.konstanz.de/HP/index.php/bibliothek/virtueller-rundgang/32-olaus-magnus-historia-de-gentibus-septentrionalibus-olaj-magnj-historien-der-mittnaechtigen-laender-hb-62x). Zitat aus der vierten Referenz:

> 16 Jahre später ließ Olaus Magnus seiner Karte eine 22-bändige mit Holzschnitten reich illustrierte Historia de gentibus septentrionalibus oder „Beschreibung der Völker des Nordens“ folgen, die einen Kommentarband zur Carta Marina darstellt. Diese fand in ganz Europa reißenden Absatz und wurde bald ins Deutsche, Französische, Italienische, Niederländische und ins Englische übersetzt. Die Suso-Bibliothek besitzt die leicht gekürzte deutsche Übersetzung der Historia von 1567, übersetzt von Johann Baptist Fickler, mit dem Titel Olaj Magnj historien, Der Mittnächtigen Länder: Von allerley Thun, Wesens, Condition, Sitten ... Warhafftige beschreibung, Deßgleichen auch von allerley ... Thieren ... / Auß selb eigner erfahrnuß ... beschryben durch ... Olavm Magnvm auß Gothien, die auch eine stark vereinfachte, aber der Carta Marina nachempfundene Faltkarte enthält, und eine lateinische Version von 1618.

Vgl. [hier](https://www.zobodat.at/pdf/Abhandlungen-Akademie-Bayern-ph-ph-hist_NF_125_0001-0319.pdf), Seite 13. Die Übersetzung von Johann Baptist Fickler ist kostenpflichtig [erhältlich](http://www.general-books.net/book.cfm?id=6992129).

Ggf. könnte auch

> Magnus, Olaus:
> Die Wunder des Nordens. Erschlossen von Elena Balzamo und Reinhard Kaiser, DIE ANDERE BIBLIOTHEK, 2006, ISBN: 3821845716

nützlich sein.

**Update:**

Karsten Theis hat den [lateinischen Originaltext](http://runeberg.org/olmagnus/0857.html) gefunden. Rot umrandet ist der in der Frage aufgeführte Text.

[image]

**Update 2:**

Die entscheidende Frage ist, wie es ausgerechnet eine deutsche Übersetzung des Textes von Olaus Magnus in eine japanische Butoh-Performance geschafft hat. Der "Vater" von Butoh ist Tatsumi Hijikata, und aus [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatsumi_Hijikata) entnimmt man

> At the time, he studied tap, jazz, flamenco, ballet and German expressionist dance (Nobutoshi Tsuda).

Zu Nobutoshi Tsuda gibt es den Artikel

> Yukihiko Yoshida, Keio University: Nobutoshi Tsuda, a master of Tatsumi Hijikata and Miki Wakamatsu , moderner Tanz and his school original Japanese,「津田信敏と門下生たち

Man beachte den deutschen Ausdruck "moderner Tanz" im Titel des japanisch geschriebenen [Artikels](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266743348_Nobutoshi_Tsuda_a_master_of_Tatsumi_Hijikata_and_Miki_Wakamatsu_moderner_Tanz_and_his_school_original_Japanesejintianxinmintomenxiashengtachi). Es scheint mir nicht unplausibel zu sein, dass die in die Frage erwähnte Tanz-Performance (inkl. Text) ihren Ursprung in Deutschland hat.

Vielleicht lohnt auch ein Blick in [Musikikonographische Stellen in Olaus Magnus' 'Historien der mittnächtigen Länder' - nach der deutschen Übersetzung von Johann Baptist Fickler, Basel 1567](http://www.rimab.ch/content/bibliographie/SCB-Bib-2009-01-331).

**Update 3:**

Vorschläge für die fehlenden Worte im rezitierten Text gemäß lateinischem Orginal:

- Bergener Meer / maria Bergensium
- und fresse dort Hummer (Langusten) / locustas
- Haar und scharfe (spitze) Schuppen, von schwarzer Farbe / squamas acutasque, atro colore
- über das Wasser empor hebt (aufrichtet) und sich nachher in einen Ring zusammenrollt / super aquas se extollens, atque in modum sphaerae convolvens

Comment: Vielen Dank, auch im Namen von Butoh-Forscher Professor Baird, für die ausführliche Antwort und die vielen hilfreichen Quellenangaben!

Comment: Hier ist die lateinische Originalversion: http://runeberg.org/olmagnus/0857.html

Comment: @KarstenTheis Vielleicht wäre es sinnvoll, mit Sachiko Kusukawa, dem Autor von *‘The sources of Gessner’s pictures for the Historia animalium’, Annals of Science, 67:  3 (2010), 303-328* Kontakt aufzunehmen - er könnte etwas über die Rezeption des nordischen Seeschlangen-Motivs in Japan wissen.